# Sci-fi novel about a girl waking up in a spaceship, on a planet populated by two alien species

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Young adult science fiction. I read this in the mid-late 1990s. I do not know when it was written.

The story is about a young girl who wakes up from stasis on a planet. I dont remember if the ship had crashed or landed there, but she is the only one who wakes up initially. The rest of the crew is alive and wakes at the end, IIRC.

She starts exploring the area and encounters two alien races, one of which preys upon the other. I think the predator species had yellow blood and was somewhat dog-like, though bipedal. There is one scene where one of the aliens falls into a river and drowns, and the girl is astounded that the others show no reaction.

I think the girl returned to the ship each night and talked to/was fed by the ship's computer.

There was something about a balance between the two races. Like, when one species got too numerous, the other had more to eat and evened out the numbers, and vice versa.

I hope someone can make anything out of my ramblings. :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the novel you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Makes me think Orson Scott Card but I dunno why